# How to convert string to byte array in Python

Tags: python

Say that I have a 4 character string, and I want to convert this string into a byte array where each character in the string is translated into its hex equivalent. e.g.

```
str = "ABCD"
```

I'm trying to get my output to be

```
array('B', [41, 42, 43, 44])
```

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: What you want is not possible, at least not in this exact form. A bytearray of type `B` contains 1-byte integers, and they are always represented in decimal.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

encode function can help you here, encode returns an encoded version of the string

```
In [44]: str = "ABCD"

In [45]: [elem.encode("hex") for elem in str]
Out[45]: ['41', '42', '43', '44']
```

or you can use array module

```
In [49]: import array

In [50]: print array.array('B', "ABCD")
array('B', [65, 66, 67, 68])
```

Comment: however as you can see,, array module gives a ascii value of string elements, which doesn't match with your expected output

Comment: This is the accepted answer and does not work in Python3. Could you please add the python3 version as pointed in other answers?

Answer (score 71):

Just use a `bytearray()` which is a list of bytes.

Python2:

```
s = "ABCD"
b = bytearray()
b.extend(s)
```

Python3:

```
s = "ABCD"
b = bytearray()
b.extend(map(ord, s))
```

By the way, don't use `str` as a variable name since that is builtin.

Comment: This is broken in 3.4: `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @KevanAhlquist my bad. Fixed it now.

Comment: For Python 3 this looks cleaner to me:
`s = "ABCD"`,
`b = bytearray()`,
`b.extend(s.encode())`

Comment: Regarding [encode()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode), it returns a bytes object which naturally extends a bytearray.

Comment: `map(ord, s)` will return values > 255 unless your strings are strictly ASCII. Please update your answer to include something like `s.encode('utf-8')`. (Note that UTF-8 is a strict superset of ASCII, so it does not alter ASCII strings in any way.)

Comment: @9000 it is incorrect to use `.encode()` as well as `.encode('utf-8')`. Use `map(ord, ...)` if you don't want you bytes to be transformed. https://repl.it/repls/MistySubtleVisitors just press `run` and see the result.

Comment: in my use case (socket send), only `b.extend(map(ord, s))` works, none of the following works:   `s.encode(), s.encode(‘ascii’), bytearray(s.encode())`

Answer (score 24):

An alternative to get a byte array is to encode the string in ascii:  `b=s.encode('ascii')`.

Comment: Assuming that the string is ASCII to begin with.  If you have s = '\x80', that's not going to work.

Comment: what if s = '\x80' what then to do?

Answer (score 13):

Depending on your needs, this can be one step or two steps

1. use `encode()` to convert string to bytes, immutable
2. use `bytearray()` to convert bytes to bytearray, mutable

```
s="ABCD"
encoded=s.encode('utf-8')
array=bytearray(encoded)
```

The following validation is done in Python 3.7

```
>>> s="ABCD"
>>> encoded=s.encode('utf-8')
>>> encoded
b'ABCD'
>>> array=bytearray(encoded)
>>> array
bytearray(b'ABCD')
```

Comment: It helped me in some other thing. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

This works for me (Python 2)

```
s = "ABCD"
b = bytearray(s)

# if you print whole b, it still displays it as if its original string
print b

# but print first item from the array to see byte value
print b[0]
```

Reference:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/bytes-python

Answer (score 9):

This work in both Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> bytearray(b'ABCD')
bytearray(b'ABCD')
```

***Note string started with `b`.***

To get individual chars:

```
>>> print("DEC HEX ASC")
... for b in bytearray(b'ABCD'):
...     print(b, hex(b), chr(b))
DEC HEX ASC
65 0x41 A
66 0x42 B
67 0x43 C
68 0x44 D
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "ABCD"
from array import array
a = array("B", s)
```

If you want hex:

```
print map(hex, a)
```

Comment: Does not work in repl.it.   Returns: "TypeError: cannot use a str to initialize an array with typecode 'B' "

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers is producing exactly `array('B', [41, 42, 43, 44])` and [the answer by avasal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624266/8849755) fails in Python 3, I post here my alternative:

```
import array
s = 'ABCD'
a = array.array('B', [ord(c) for c in s])
print(a)
```

which prints

```
array('B', [65, 66, 67, 68])
```

Note that 65-68 is the correct ASCII for "ABCD".

Answer (score -1):

for python 3 it worked for what @HYRY posted. I needed it for a returned data in a dbus.array. This is the only way it worked

```
s = "ABCD"
```

from array import array

```
a = array("B", s)
```