# How to convert hex str to an hex bytearray

Tags: python, string, hex, arrays

i would convert the following byte content as str using python to an bytearray

`'0B C0 C0 C0 C8 FF 43 ED 44 C0 \r\n'`

like below

`bytearray(b'\x0b\xc0\xc0\xc0\xc8\xffC\xedD\xc0')`

how it can be done?

Comment: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624190/python-convert-string-to-byte-array) thread

Comment: All you need to do is remove the spaces, then apply one of the answers in the duplicate.

Comment: `bytearray.fromhex('0B C0 C0 C0 C8 FF 43 ED 44 C0 \r\n'.translate(dict.fromkeys((10, 13, 32))))`.