# How I can realize it in Python3?

Tags: c#, python

I have some c# code. Could you, please, clarify how can do the same encoding result Python:

```
byte[] result = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("some_string")));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? To be specific, why do you base64-encode and then base64-decode again?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. Why are you converting a string to an array of bytes, only to then encode to and directly afterwrds decode from Base64, only to contain the bytes?

Wouldn't `var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("myString")` be better suited?

Comment: @someone  it is not my code - I just only need to get the same result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624190/python-convert-string-to-byte-array

Comment: i will recommend reading the guidline [ask], and [mcve]. As Simply formulating a question will give you the answer. First you have to define what the C# code does: It take a `string` and return a `byte[]`. Then you make few test of this C# code storing input and output, it will become your test case.  Step 3 you reformulate step 1 into a search engine: "python string to byte array". Step 4, you try solution you find and write an SO question specifying your input/output and the expected result.

Comment: You can use step 4 only if the previous step failed. Beeing clear, and able to describe an issue could be one of the most valuable skill you can get in IT.

Answer (score 0):

import base64
base64.b64encode(b'some_string')

Comment: In this case, I get not the same result.

Comment: Your code definitely doesn't seem to produce the same result to me, as it encodes a string to base64, while the C# code encodes it and then decodes it again.