# How to convert a list of strings to a bytearray?

Tags: python-3.x

How would I convert a list of strings to a bytearray, then get the a certain value that is part of the list back into a string?

Here is my code:

```py
test_list = ['Hello', 'World']
a = '|'.join(test_list)

test_array = bytearray(a.encode('utf-8'))
print(test_array)

# test("Hello")
print("Count of bytes:", len(byte_array))

# How would I get "Hello" back into a string?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to byte array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624190/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-array-in-python)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *'get "Hello" back into a string'*. "Hello" already is a string.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the rest of the question? (1) there is no list here (2) you seem to know how to create a bytearray

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? I have the feeling this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Is your question now how you can split the bytearray at the `|` character?

Comment: So I am wondering if it is possible to turn a list into a byte array then turn it back into a list so that I can get the values? Sorry I edited my code to make it clearer.